# How to generate a termcap string from a compiled terminfo file?

Tags: ncurses, terminfo, termcap

The thread's title pretty much says it all.

When I googled this question, I found mentions of a program called `untic` that supposedly does what I want to do, but this program does not seem to be available in any of my distro's (Debian) official packages.

Is there some other way to go from (compiled) terminfo to termcap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`man infotocap`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infotocap.1m.html):

> infotocap - convert a terminfo description into a termcap description

which notes

> This utility is actually a link to [**`tic`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html), running in **`-C`**  mode.   You  can
> use other **`tic`** options such as **`-f`** and  **`-x`**.

That's source-to-source.  For compiled terminfo to source (either terminfo or termcap), use [`infocmp`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html):

> The source produced by the **`-C`** option may be used directly as a  termcap
> entry,  but not all parameterized strings can be changed to the termcap
> format.  **`infocmp`** will attempt to  convert  most  of  the  parameterized
> information,  and  anything not converted will be plainly marked in the
> output and commented out.  These should be edited by hand.

`infocmp` is used in several ways; converting to termcap is only one of those:

> **`infocmp`**  can  be  used  to  compare  a binary terminfo entry with other terminfo entries, rewrite a terminfo description to take  advantage  of the  **`use=`**  terminfo field, or *print out a terminfo description from the binary file (term) in a variety of formats.*  In all cases, the  boolean fields  will be printed first, followed by the numeric fields, followed by the string fields.

tic and infocmp assume things about the location of terminal databases, which are dealt with in the manual pages, e.g., [`TERMINFO`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO).  For an arbitrary filename (not part of the terminal database), you could use a script to copy it into a directory like the conventional terminal database, e.g.,

```bash
#!/bin/sh
mytemp=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'rm -rf "$mytemp"; exit 1' INT QUIT TERM HUP
trap 'rm -rf "$mytemp"; exit 0' EXIT
TERMINFO=$mytemp; export TERMINFO
TERMINFO_DIRS=$mytemp; export TERMINFO_DIRS

for name in "$@"
do
        [ -f "$name" ] || continue
        case $(file "$name") in
        *Compiled\ *terminfo\ entry*)
                actual=$(file "$name" | sed -E -e 's%^.*"([^"]+)".*$%\1%')
                leader=$(echo "$actual" | sed -E -e 's%^(.).*%\1%')
                part="$mytemp/$leader"
                mkdir -p "$part"
                cp "$name" "$part/$actual"
                full="$part/$actual"
                infocmp -C -T "$actual" | sed -e "s%$full%$name%"
                ;;
        esac
done
```

That is not **completely** general, since some platforms (using ncurses) use different structures, as outlined in the [`term`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/term.5.html) manual page.

Comment: Thank you, but when I try `infocmp -C <path_to_terminfo_file>`, I get the error: `infocmp: couldn't open terminfo file <path_to_terminfo_file>.`  The `file` utility reports that the file at `<path_to_terminfo_file>` is a "Compiled terminfo entry."  Therefore, I do not understand `infocmp`'s error message...

Comment: The parameter for `infocmp` is the name of a terminal description, not a `<path_to_terminfo_file>`.

Comment: Thank you again.  I am sorry for being so dense, but I just don't understand how to apply the information in your answer to my problem.  If I have a compiled terminfo file at `/path/to/foo.terminfo`, and I want to convert it to a termcap entry, to be stored in the file `/path/to/foo.termcap`, what are the *specific commands* I must run?  Could you post that in your answer?  I stress the fact that `/path/to/foo.terminfo` is an *arbitrary filepath* (as opposed to a path with a "standard" name at a "standard" location, such as, for instance, `/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm+256color`).

Comment: Thank you!!!  I really appreciate the script you posted.  I learned a lot from it!  (In particular, I learned that the problem is unreasonably difficult!  It seems to me bizarre that such a translation from one format to another would require so much hoop-jumping...)